# Why does my linear-gradient only apply to one page?

Tags: html, css

I have the same CSS file linked to three different HTML documents. The CSS looks something like:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.7);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,0,0,1), rgba(255,255,255,1));
}
```

The HTML that links the CSS file (in the *head* tags) looks like:

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/style.css">
```

And it is copied and pasted between the three documents. My issue is that the linear-gradient only applies to my starting page (**index.html**). On my other two pages, the fail-safe **background-color** displays. What's the reason for this issue?

Comment: the pages are empty?

Comment: They're not though

Comment: did you clear your cache ?

Comment: Are the other three documents in the root of your project too?

Comment: Clearing my cache worked, although I'm not sure why. Thanks

Comment: Clearing the cache worked because your browser didn't request your css file because it sill has some version of it in it's cache. When clearing the cache, the browser requests the file again (so it got the "newest version") and the changes got applied.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I tested doing this & came up with the problem. You might not have the same height on the pages. When I had nothing on the page & did this you could not see the gradient, but when I changed it to 100vh it worked.

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Try it out with different heights & it should work the same.

Answer (score -1):

Two ways of doing this the way I see it, one is to directly have the CSS in your HTML file within the `<style>` tags, you would have that on all of your desired pages.

Second way of doing it is to add a class in your separate files:

```
`.class body {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
     background-color:  rgba(255, 0, 0,. 7);
     background-image: linear-gradiant(180deg, rgba(250, 0, 0, 1), 
     rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
     }`
```